# On delete trigger insert value to else table

Tags: sql, t-sql

The question is the following: I create a trigger for deleting an element from the table, and I want to pull this element (which I deleted) into the Temp table, how can I pull this element in T-SQL, in this case, instead of 'Value', there should be a deleted element.

```
Create Trigger TankFarmDelete
On TankFarm
After Delete
as
    insert into TankFarmTemp 
    values ('Value')
```

Comment: *"there should be a deleted element"* Yes, it's called `deleted`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use the `deleted` pseudo-table:

```
Create Trigger TankFarmDelete On TankFarm After Delete
as
begin
    insert into TankFarmTemp 
        select element
        from deleted;
end;
```